# Is there any ActionScript library for turning simple wiki mark up into html?

Tags: html, actionscript-3, wiki, markup

So what I need is simple - a flash/flex application for turning wiki Google like mark up into html. In actionscript and mxml. Is there anything like that?

When do you need such thing? - you need it when you create an app for some multiple editors at the same time to work on one document, probably on same line and share ideas while live wideo charting. Such app can be done using as3 and Red5 for exalmple...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a good candidate for regular expressions. In fact, I think  the book "Mastering Regular Expressions" actually uses wiki markup to HTML as an example project.